# Remove between time in pandas dataframe in loop

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to recursively drop dataframe rows that are located between defined time delta - as shown in Figure.[image: Which time series to drop]

I prepared following snippet of code:

```
import pandas as pd

time_series = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=100, freq='ms')
df = pd.Series(range(len(time_series)), index=time_series)
print(df)
df = df.drop(df.between_time("00:00:00.003", "00:00:00.098").index)
```

The range of time filtered should be date independent and take into account only difference in hour. How should I drop non necessary data located in "drop" sections presented in Figure? The loop should be until the end of dataframe that contains about 100 millions of rows.

Comment: You want to keep only 0,1,2,99 every 100ms, right? Said differenly 4 on 100 rows with a recurring pattern?

Comment: Not exactly, it is an example only. I would like to keep rows by predefined timedelta, because number of rows may be variable and not corresponding to number of rows.

Comment: I can propose a parameterized way, provided you clearly say what the parameters should be... Currently I cannot really guess.

Comment: The parameters can be free, of your choice, basing on Figure. If you have 100ms, you can assume that rows will be dropped every 20ms and left for 5ms.

Comment: Please do not repost the same question multiple times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60756220/pandas-drop-rows-by-time-duration, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766675/dataframe-drop-between-time-multiple-rows-by-shifting-timedelta. If you have something minor to add, you can always edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
i = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=100, freq='ms')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(100)}, index=i)
df.drop(df.between_time(*pd.to_datetime(['00:00:00.003', '00:00:00.098']).time).index, inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
                          A
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000   0
2018-01-01 00:00:00.001   1
2018-01-01 00:00:00.002   2
2018-01-01 00:00:00.099  99
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be dropping anything?

Comment: I added `inplace=True` to the code so it will drop inplace (not return a copy).

Answer (score 0):

This code keeps every row by 3 minute intervals given your series

```
import pandas as pd
time_series = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=100000000, freq='ms')
df = pd.Series(range(len(time_series)), index=time_series)
df2=df.to_frame()
df2.columns = ['every_3rd_minute']
df2 = df2[df2.every_3rd_minute % 180000 == 0]
print(df2)
```

produces

```
                   every_3rd_minute
2018-01-01 00:00:00                 0
2018-01-01 00:03:00            180000
2018-01-01 00:06:00            360000
2018-01-01 00:09:00            540000
2018-01-01 00:12:00            720000
...                               ...
2018-01-02 03:33:00          99180000
2018-01-02 03:36:00          99360000
2018-01-02 03:39:00          99540000
2018-01-02 03:42:00          99720000
2018-01-02 03:45:00          99900000

[556 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: This is what I asked about, but how to keep every in example rows that last for 1 second, in every 3 minutes?

Comment: How many milliseconds in a second? 1000. So change the 180000 in the code to 1000

Comment: But this code drops only one row in every 1 second. My question is how to drop multiple rows that correspond to in example 0.1 second duration.

Comment: it actually only KEEPS a row every every second. It drops all the other rows in between. You could implement a for loop to keep as many rows as you want. can you be more specific about WHICH rows you want to keep?

Comment: I would like to keep rows that last for desired time_delta, in example for 0.1 second. In next time_delta that last for example 3 seconds, rows are being dropped. And again until the end of dataframe. You suggest a for loop, but could it be possible with oneliner that utilizes i.e. lambda function?

Comment: You defined your initial data frame with each row having the same duration ( a millisecond). After .1 seconds, how many rows do you want to keep- .1 seconds’ worth? I do not understand the size of the ‘gap’ interval and the size of the ‘kept’ interval based on your description.

Comment: Looking at your code, we have 0.001s interval. Entire dataframe lasts for 1 day and 3.75h. Then how to have new dataframe that kept data from 0.1s every 1 hour, for example? It is worth to mention, that in original dataframe I have multiple columns, of which each has different probing frequency, so I should base on time, not constant number of rows interval.