# Pandas drop rows by time duration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I would like to drop dataframe rows by time condition (ignoring date). My data contains around 100 million rows. I have around 100 columns and each column has different sampling frequency.
[image: Idea of dropping rows]

I prepared following snippet of code that takes into account different sampling frequency:

```py
import pandas as pd

# leave_duration=0.01 seconds
# drop_duration=0.1 seconds

i = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=1000, freq='2ms')
i=i.append(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=1000, freq='3ms'))
i=i.append(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=1000, freq='0.5ms'))
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(len(i))}, index=i)
df=df.sort_index()
print(df)
# drop by duration....
```

In this simple example, there is data that lasts for around 1 second, and has 3 different sampling frequencies. The goal is to drop rows that last for (eg) 0.1 second duration and leave rows of (eg) 0.01 second duration. How can I do it with a one-liner?

Comment: you need data for mentioned dates of its you total data, I'm not clear about what you exactly need. mentioned df is your desire dates that you want filter those out from you total data?

Comment: I posted a  answer but after read you question again I fall in doubt that did i get your question clear or not

Comment: Yes, I would like to filter out data (rows) that lie between time range.

Comment: check the answer that I posted, you can filter your desire date by `df=df.loc['2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000 ':'2018-01-01 00:00:00.000500 '] ` please let me know if we aren't in same page

Comment: But how to do it by ignoring date and by taking into account time only? And it is single loc, how to expand the function if I have 100 milion rows?

Comment: please let us to know what is your desire output format, mention it in tablure format

Comment: Desired output format is exactly as you have shown, but you filtered only single range. What to do if you want to filter in example 1000 (multiple) time deltas as shown in original Figure in question?

Comment: There should be multiple filtrations, with constant time_delta. It may be assumed as in first question: ```# leave_duration=0.01 seconds
# drop_duration=0.1 seconds```

Comment: I think I got your question, I filtered out one specific range, you want this plus some shifted dates

Comment: Exactly yes! I have 100 million rows and I want to filter shifted times (in example shift by 1 second, filter 0.1s duration), not dates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove between time in pandas dataframe in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637330/remove-between-time-in-pandas-dataframe-in-loop)

Answer (score 0):

by `df=df.loc['2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000 ':'2018-01-01 00:00:00.000500 ']` you will have new df witch data are between `2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000` and `2018-01-01 00:00:00.000500`
now you can apply you filter for desire dates

```
import pandas as pd

# leave_duration=0.01 seconds
# drop_duration=0.1 seconds

i = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=1000, freq='2ms')
i=i.append(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=1000, freq='3ms'))
i=i.append(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=1000, freq='0.5ms'))
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(len(i))}, index=i)
df=df.sort_index()
print(df)

#filter data between 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000 ':'2018-01-01 00:00:00.000500
df=df.loc['2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000 ':'2018-01-01 00:00:00.000500 ']
print(df)
```

Output:
Before data filter applied

```
                               A
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000     0
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000  2000
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000  1000
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000500  2001
2018-01-01 00:00:00.001000  2002
...                          ...
2018-01-01 00:00:02.985000  1995
2018-01-01 00:00:02.988000  1996
2018-01-01 00:00:02.991000  1997
2018-01-01 00:00:02.994000  1998
2018-01-01 00:00:02.997000  1999

[3000 rows x 1 columns]
```

After date filter applied:

```
                               A
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000     0
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000  2000
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000  1000
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000500  2001
```