# Dataframe drop between_time multiple rows by shifting timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to drop multiple groups of rows by time criterion. Date criterion may be ignored. 
I have dataframe that contains 100 million rows, with around 0.001s sampling frequency - but it is variable for different columns.
The goal is to drop multiple rows by criterion of "shifting". The leave duration might be 0.01 seconds and the drop duration might be 0.1 second, as shown in Figure:

[image: The idea of dropping rows]

I have many problems with Timestamp to Time conversions and with the defining the oneliner that will drop multiple groups of rows.
I made tries with following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta#, timestamp
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

# leave_duration=0.01 seconds
# drop_duration=0.1 seconds

i = pd.date_range('2018-01-01 00:01:15.004', periods=1000, freq='2ms')
i=i.append(pd.date_range('2018-01-01 00:01:15.004', periods=1000, freq='3ms'))
i=i.append(pd.date_range('2018-01-01 00:01:15.004', periods=1000, freq='0.5ms'))
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(len(i))}, index=i)
df=df.sort_index()

minimum_time=df.index.min()
print("Minimum time:",minimum_time)
maximum_time=df.index.max()
print("Maximum time:",maximum_time)

# futuredate = minimum_time + timedelta(microseconds=100)

print("Dataframe before dropping:\n",df)
df.drop(df.between_time(*pd.to_datetime([minimum_time, maximum_time]).time).index, inplace=True)
print("Dataframe after dropping:\n",df)

# minimum_time=str(minimum_time).split()
# minimum_time=minimum_time[1]
# print(minimum_time)
# maximum_time=str(maximum_time).split()
# maximum_time=maximum_time[1]
# print(maximum_time)
```

How can I drop rows by time criterion, with shifting?

Comment: the DataFrame after dropping is empty because your minimum on (date, time) is also your minimum on (time) only. Same applies to max. Otherwise, your code seems to match your expectancies... Please tell me if you need further help.

Comment: Matt (below) already answered me question. But this is slow approach - if you can help me with improving this answer to work with large dataframes - it would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove between time in pandas dataframe in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637330/remove-between-time-in-pandas-dataframe-in-loop)

Comment: Have you not quite a similar question twice already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637330/remove-between-time-in-pandas-dataframe-in-loop, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60756220/pandas-drop-rows-by-time-duration.

Comment: I didn't find an answer to my question, so I asked the question at different hour and after couple of days spent on searching for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working for me:

```
df = df.loc[(df.index - df.index[0]) % pd.to_timedelta('110ms') > pd.to_timedelta('100ms')]
```

Comment: Fortunately, I noticed your editions. Your code is phenomenal and works quickly. Compared to the dictionary approach, 257x acceleration was achieved! Your answer is the answer I expected - an oneliner.

Answer (score 1):

I *think this is what you're looking for. If not, it hopefully gets you closer.

I defined drop periods by taking the minimum time and incrementing it by your drop/leave times. I then append it to a dictionary where the key is the start of the drop period and the value is the end of the drop period.

Lastly I just iterate through the dictionary and drop rows that fall between those two times in your dataframe, shedding rows at each step.

```
drop_periods = {}
start_drop = minimum_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=0.01)
end_drop = start_drop + datetime.timedelta(seconds=0.1)
drop_periods[start_drop] = end_drop
while end_drop < maximum_time:
    start_drop = end_drop + datetime.timedelta(seconds=0.01)
    end_drop = start_drop + datetime.timedelta(seconds=0.1)
    drop_periods[start_drop] = end_drop


for start, end in drop_periods.items():
    print("Dataframe before dropping:\n", len(df))
    df.drop(df.between_time(*pd.to_datetime([start, end]).time).index, inplace=True)
    print("Dataframe after dropping:\n", len(df))
```

Comment: This is working answer and I accept this answer. But on the other hand, it is inefficient for large dataframes - I asked about this issue in other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60790843/optimization-of-large-pandas-dataframe-and-loop-in-dictionary-performance-issu